# Is there the way to parse time with timezone in Qt?

Tags: string, qt, parsing, time, timezone

I need to parse strings with time like '09:21:15 EST' (where EST is US Eastern timezone), so that the information about summer / winter time (daylight saving time) is correct, so that UTC−05:00 is used for winter dates, and UTC−04:00 for summer dates.

It is also necessary to support the direct setting of the UTC offset - '09:21:15 UTC−04:00', in which case daylight saving time should not be taken.

I Didn't find anything intelligible and sensible in Qt documentation for QDateTime, QDate, QTime, QTimeZone etc.

Is there an easy way to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qt QDateTime from string with timezone and daylight saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55370667/qt-qdatetime-from-string-with-timezone-and-daylight-saving)

Answer (score 3):

In general, in *any* language, what you ask cannot be done reliably.

- `EST` is not a *time zone*.  It's an English abbreviation for an *aspect* of a time zone.
- There are places that use EST without EDT, such as Jamaica for example.  [See more here.](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/est)
- There are non-English abbreviations to consider, such as `HNE` that's used in places in French-speaking Canada such as Montréal.
- Many abbreviations are *ambiguous*.  For example `CST` could be Central Standard Time, Cuba Standard Time, or China Standard Time.
- Many time zones don't have *any* abbreviation - even in English.  They are sometimes given invented (made up, artificial) abbreviations that aren't legal or in common usage, but in reality they are referred to by their country name or only by their UTC offset (for a given timestamp).
- In order to convert between time zones reliably for multiple timestamps, you need an [IANA time zone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), such as `"America/New_York"`.  [`QTimeZone`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimezone.html) can work with these.
- On any given timestamp you can have an offset from UTC, such as `-05:00`.  You can set an offset when using [`QDateTime`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html).
- If you are *absolutely sure* you are only working with timestamps from North America containing common English abbreviations, you *could* build and use an opinionated mapping between string and offset, such as `"EST" == -5`, `"EDT" == -4`, `"CST" == -6`, `"CDT" == -5`, etc.  But it can only map abbreviation to *offset*, not to a *time zone*.  (See also "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).)

Answer (score 1):

Qt likely has the features you need already implemented.

With [`QDateTime::fromString`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#fromString-2) you can use `t` in the `format` string to mark timezone characters.

Have a look into this question as well: [Qt QDateTime from string with timezone and daylight saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55370667/qt-qdatetime-from-string-with-timezone-and-daylight-saving)
There you can get an example, which shows that you need the `QDateTime` in the `LocalTime` specification to be able to deal with daylight saving times.
However, [`QDateTime::offsetFromUtc`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#offsetFromUtc)  is dependent from the `QDateTime`'s current specification...
I guess, you would need to always convert the QDateTime object to the same [TimeSpec](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#toTimeSpec) before comparing `offsetFromUtc`